# How to send a http delete request in SvelteKit when the user closes the page in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, svelte, sveltekit

In my SvelteKit app, I want to send a HTTP delete request when the user closes the page. This is what I have tried.

In my routes folder, there are two files. The first one is +page.svelte and the other one
is +server.ts. Both files are in the same directory.

Inside my +page.svelte file, I have the following code:

```html
<script>

    import {onMount} from 'svelte';

    onMount(()=>{
        window.onunload = function(){
        fetch('/', {
            method: 'DELETE',
            keepalive: true
        })
    }});
 
</script>
<h1>Welcome to SvelteKit</h1>
<p>Visit <a href="https://kit.svelte.dev">kit.svelte.dev</a> to read the documentation</p>
```

Inside my +server.ts file, I have the following code:

```js
import { json } from "@sveltejs/kit";

export function DELETE(){
    console.log('delete');
    return json({message: 'delete'})
}
```

When I run the server, if I navigate to http://localhost:5173 and then close the page, I did not see 'delete' being printed out in the VS code terminal. This means that the delete request is not made. How should I modify my code so that the delete request is succesfully made when the user closes the page? By the way, the browser that I am using to test my code is FireFox 116.0.3.

Comment: You can attach events on the window via [`<svelte:window>`](https://svelte.dev/docs/special-elements#svelte-window), that way the listener is cleaned up together with the component automatically. You also should not use the `on...` properties (like `onunload` here), pretty much ever. If anything use `addEventListener` & `removeEventListener`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is *no* reliable way of doing that. The process running the browser can be killed at any point for a number of reasons.

If the user is in some unfinished process, you could use [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) to prompt the user when they try to leave the page. But as noted, this is not guaranteed to fire, so you should not rely on this mechanism for any critical logic. For cleanup, you may have to rely on timeouts, i.e. if the server does not hear from a user for a long time, clean up any temporary state/data associated with the session/user.